# Take me to a particular activity when notification is tapped

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, audio-player, android-music-player

I have an  activity (Musicplayer.class) which plays music and a notification is shown when the track starts playing however when I tap on the notifaction it takes me back to the main activiy (1st activiy of the app)
How do I modify the code so that tapping the notification takes me to the music player activity.

the code is taken from the android documentation ( see below )

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MusicPlayer.this)
                // set values....

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(MusicPlayer.this, MusicPlayer.class);
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(MusicPlayer.this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MusicPlayer.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


             mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            final int mId = 1;
            mNotificationManager.notify(mId,mBuilder.build());
```

changed code to this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

and now the activity duplicates (two same activities running, same music playing 2 times)

Comment: Tapping on the notification takes you to the activity passed while creating the resultIntent.  Change it to the class/activity you want to be launched.

Comment: Just change the launch mode in the manifest to 'singleTop', that will avoid the class from being re-instantiated, if it's already running.  see Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode